# How to use Gurobi to solve this optimization problem?

Tags: java, gurobi

the problem is follow:

```
object:min z
s.t.
 r1 >= 0 
 r2 >= 0
 r3 >= 0 
 r1 + r2 + r3 = 1
 15 * (1 - r1) <= z
 12 * (1 - r2) <= z
 12 * (1 - r3) <= z
 240 * r1 <= z
 27 * r2 <= z
 27 * r3 <= z
```

or like this format:

```
object:
 min z; z = max( 15 * (1 - r1), 12 * (1 - r2), 12 * (1 - r3) ,240 * r1, 27 * r2, 27 * r3)
s.t.
 r1 >= 0 
 r2 >= 0
 r3 >= 0 
 r1 + r2 + r3 = 1
```

This problem is from a paper, in this paper, the author used Gurobi to solve the problem. I download Gurobi and studied the LP examples, but the example's object is like `min x + y + 2 z`.
I want to know if this problem can be solved by Guribo,if the answer is yes, how to write the model.
Thank u very much.

Comment: You didn't mention if you want to use Gurobi from a specific language. You could use it from Python, C, C++, Java, .NET, R and Matlab to create and solve your optimization problems. It's also possible to call it [directly from the command line](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/gurobi_command_line_tool.html) to solve your lp. I'd recommend to [model your lp](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.0/CPLEX-format.htm) and solve it via `gurobi_cl yourlp.lp`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment，I use the Java api in Gurobi.

Comment: What bothers me now is that the objective function is not a certain function.the object value 'z' depends on a series of funcitons, I don't konw how to model this lp, could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: To double up what @joni said, `.lp` files are easy to create, human readable and probably more versatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should admit I'm not a big fan of java and it's the first time I used Gurobi's Java Interface, so it might not be the most elegant solution. Anyway, here's a way to model and solve your problem in Java:

```
// example.java
import gurobi.*;

public class example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      GRBEnv    env   = new GRBEnv("example.log");
      GRBModel  model = new GRBModel(env);

      // Create variables
      GRBVar r1 = model.addVar(0.0, GRB.INFINITY, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "r1");
      GRBVar r2 = model.addVar(0.0, GRB.INFINITY, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "r2");
      GRBVar r3 = model.addVar(0.0, GRB.INFINITY, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "r3");
      GRBVar z = model.addVar(-GRB.INFINITY, GRB.INFINITY, 1.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "z");

      // Set objective: minimize z
      GRBLinExpr expr = new GRBLinExpr();
      expr.addTerm(1.0, z);
      model.setObjective(expr, GRB.MINIMIZE);

      // Add constraint: r1 + r2 + r3 = 1
      expr = new GRBLinExpr();
      expr.addTerm(1.0, r1); expr.addTerm(1.0, r2); expr.addTerm(1.0, r3);
      model.addConstr(expr, GRB.EQUAL, 1.0, "c0");

      // Add constraint: 15 * (1-r1) <= z  <-> -15 r1 - z <= -15
      expr = new GRBLinExpr();
      expr.addTerm(-15.0, r1); expr.addTerm(-1.0, z);
      model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, -15.0, "c1");

      // Add constraint: 12 * (1-r2) <= z  <-> -12 r2 - z <= -12
      expr = new GRBLinExpr();
      expr.addTerm(-12.0, r2); expr.addTerm(-1.0, z);
      model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, -12.0, "c1");

      // Add constraint: 12 * (1-r3) <= z  <-> -12 r3 - z <= -12
      expr = new GRBLinExpr();
      expr.addTerm(-12.0, r3); expr.addTerm(-1.0, z);
      model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, -12.0, "c1");

      // Add constraint: 240 r1 <= z  <-> 240 r1 - z <= 0
      expr = new GRBLinExpr();
      expr.addTerm(240.0, r1); expr.addTerm(-1.0, z);
      model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, 0.0, "c1");

      // Add constraint: 27 r2 <= z  <-> 27 r2 - z <= 0
      expr = new GRBLinExpr();
      expr.addTerm(27.0, r2); expr.addTerm(-1.0, z);
      model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, 0.0, "c1");

      // Add constraint: 27 r3 <= z  <-> 27 r3 - z <= 0
      expr = new GRBLinExpr();
      expr.addTerm(27.0, r3); expr.addTerm(-1.0, z);
      model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, 0.0, "c1");

      // Optimize model
      model.write("model.lp");
      model.optimize();

      System.out.println(r1.get(GRB.StringAttr.VarName)
                         + " " +r1.get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X));
      System.out.println(r2.get(GRB.StringAttr.VarName)
                         + " " +r2.get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X));
      System.out.println(r3.get(GRB.StringAttr.VarName)
                         + " " +r3.get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X));

      System.out.println("Obj: " + model.get(GRB.DoubleAttr.ObjVal));

      // Dispose of model and environment

      model.dispose();
      env.dispose();

    } catch (GRBException e) {
      System.out.println("Error code: " + e.getErrorCode() + ". " +
                         e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

This will also create a `model.lp` file which contains your LP:

```
Minimize
    obj: z
Subject To
    c0: r1 + r2 + r3 = 1
    c1: -15 r1 - z <= -15
    c2: -12 r2 - z <= -12
    c3: -12 r3 - z <= -12
    c4: 240 r1 - z <= 0
    c5: 27 r2 - z <= 0
    c6: 27 r3 - z <= 0
Bounds
    r1 >= 0
    r2 >= 0
    r3 >= 0
End
```

For such a small problem I'd recommend to write your LP directly in such a [model file](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/lp_format.html). Then you can solve it from the command line via [Gurobi's command line tool](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/gurobi_command_line_tool.html):

```
gurobi_cl ResultFile=model.sol model.lp
```

where `model.sol` is the file containing the solution.

Note that you don't need to use Gurobi for such a simple LP. There are a handful of good non-commercial solvers ( 
[lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) or [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) for example) that can solve this problem easily. With GLPK you could solve it via

```
glpsol --cpxlp model.lp -o solution.txt
```

from the command line. The `--cpxlp` flag tells glpk that model.lp is written in the cplex format, while `-o solution.txt` tells glpk to write the solution to the file solution.txt.

Comment: That answer is great, and I found the the reason that caused me to go wrong is:1.I am not pay attention to the use of spaces. 2.I didn't  write the variable 'z' to the left of the inequality.